# Is there a regular expression to get only two numbers in a string if they appear after a pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I tries using the expression `source {15}(\d+){2}\n` in a string such as the following

```
'''
FEATURES             Location
   source               1..2558
                        /organism="name"
                        /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                        /submitter_seqid="scaffold077"
'''
```

in order to get the numbers 1 and 2558, and it returned nothing.

I'd love to get ideas on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part `(\d+){2}` repeats 2 times a capture group matching 1 or more digits, matching at least 2 digits right after each other.

You could capture the first digits in group 1,  match the dots and capture the next digits in group 2 without using a quantifier for the groups.

```
source {15}(\d+)\.\.(\d+)\n
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTdSXS/1)

Answer (score 2):

You may also use a positive look-behind that is a zero-width match, so it asserts, but does not capture, the match.
You match only digits either after a `' '` or a `.`.

```
(?<= |\.)[0-9]+
```

Comment: It's a good idea but it needs a limit in order to return only the numbers 1 and 2558, otherwise other numbers are returned as well.

Comment: Yes I focused on the example provided but you are right, you could in that case return only the first two occurences [:2]